# Under what conditions will $f(x)^n$ converge pointwise and uniformly?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

Let $f(x)$ be a continuous function on $[0,1]$. Under what conditions on $f$ will the sequence $f_n(x)$ = $(f(x))^n$ converge uniformly and pointwise?

Comment: Are you asking for the definitions?

Comment: No I understand the definitions. I'm simply asking under what conditions will the sequence converge uniformly and pointwise

Answer (score 1):

To get you started: What if $|f(x)|>1$ for some $x?$ What if $|f(x)|<1$ for all $x?$